# Oracle SQL grouping set returning more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, group-by

I am working on an Oracle sql script that displays the average for one department location(`location_id = 1700`) in comparison to *all other* department locations (`location_id <> 1700`)--since it's comparing two values, I am looking to only have two rows returned. I was able to work out one query like this:

```
select d.LOCATION_ID, round(avg(e.salary),2) AS "AVG SALARY", count(d.LOCATION_ID) from departments d
join employees e on e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID
where d.location_id = 1700
group by grouping sets(d.LOCATION_ID);
```

This returns a single row for me as such: 
[image]

My second query returns four rows instead of a single one (like I thought it would):

```
select round(avg(e.salary),2) AS "AVG SALARY", count(d.LOCATION_ID) from departments d
join employees e on e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID
where d.location_id <> 1700
group by grouping sets(d.LOCATION_ID);
```

This returns 4 rows, but I am looking to have it return only 1: 
[image]

My hope was to work out both queries, then union them together--obviously I need to get over the hurdle of the second query before putting them together. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try remove the group bys altogether.  It sounds like you just want the average where location_id = 1700 and where location_id <> 1700 then UNION the two results.

```
select '1700' as "LOCATION", round(avg(e.salary),2) AS "AVG SALARY", count(d.LOCATION_ID) as "COUNT"
from departments d
join employees e on e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID
where d.location_id = 1700

union

select '<>1700' as "LOCATION", round(avg(e.salary),2) AS "AVG SALARY", count(d.LOCATION_ID) as "COUNT"
from departments d
join employees e on e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID
where d.location_id <> 1700
```

Comment: Thanks, I was shoehorning myself with the `group by` statements

Answer (score 1):

`location_id` should be included in the `select` for the second query. Now you can use `union all` to combine the result sets.

```
select d.location_id, round(avg(e.salary),2) AS "AVG SALARY", count(d.LOCATION_ID) 
from departments d
join employees e on e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID
where d.location_id <> 1700
group by d.location_id
```

This could however, be expressed in one query using conditional aggregation as

```
select
avg(case when d.location_id = 1700 then e.salary else 0 end) 
AS "AVG SALARY for location 1700", 
avg(case when d.location_id <> 1700 then e.salary else 0 end) 
AS "AVG SALARY for locations other than 1700"
from departments d
join employees e on e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using a `case` instead of `locationid`:

```
select (case when d.lcoation_id = 1700 then 1700 else -1 end) as LocationId,
       round(avg(e.salary), 2) AS "AVG SALARY",
       count(d.LOCATION_ID)
from departments d join
     employees e
     on e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID
group by grouping sets((case when d.lcoation_id = 1700 then 1700 else -1 end));
```

I'm not sure if you need the `grouping sets`.  If you only want two rows, then this probably does what you want:

```
select (case when d.lcoation_id = 1700 then 1700 else -1 end) as LocationId,
       round(avg(e.salary), 2) AS "AVG SALARY",
       count(d.LOCATION_ID)
from departments d join
     employees e
     on e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID
group by (case when d.lcoation_id = 1700 then 1700 else -1 end);
```